# Using \raisebox and \displaylimits on an integral sign

Tags: superscripts, integral

As part of a larger project, I am trying to lower the superscript `a` of the following integral so that it touches the integral sign itself.  Here is the code I am using:

```
$$\int\displaylimits^{\mathrel{\raisebox{-2pt}{a}}}$$
```

If I make the `/raisebox` parameter positive, I can lift `a` high above the integral sign, but I'm not able to lower it at all.

Comment: A little question: What's the purpose of the `\mathrel` wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, it appears you need something else in the superscriot and subscript to move the box relative to.  Also, there is a limit how far it will move depending on the height and depth.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle x 
\int\displaylimits^{\null\raisebox{-2pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\scriptstyle a$}}_{\null\raisebox{1.2pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\scriptstyle b$}}
\int\displaylimits^a_b$

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 4):

The result looks *hideous*. Don’t do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\moveintsubscript[1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.3\fontdimen6\scriptfont2\relax}{%
    $\scriptstyle\mkern-12mu#1$}%
}
\begin{document}
Why would you ever want this ugly thing:
\[
\int_{\moveintsubscript{a}}
\]
when you can use
\[
\int\limits_a
\]
just fine?
\end{document}
```

[image: integral]